# Why Catch is not catching errors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I execute the function 'request' submitting a number which the api wont return 200 I will get an error in the app. Why the catch is not catching does errors?

https://codeshare.io/5wWo9p

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page; questions need to stand on their own. You should also be very specific where *exactly* the error occurs, and include code only *directly* relevant to the question.

Comment: In the constructor, can you try the following:      this.request = this.request.bind(this);  This would go after super(props);

Comment: 404 resolves in an empty object, check response.status to see if it's above or equal to 400

Comment: @HMR I get 404 error, but why the catch is not catching that? yes, im new to js

Comment: How can I handle it

Comment: It is not catching because `fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/9038842984').then(res=>res.json());` does not throw, it resolves in an empty object (bad api behavior as it should resolve in an object containing an error).  Look for the text 404 on [this document page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) You can also check response.ok to see if it was successful.

Comment: @HMR I added a try catch containing the whole request and i still get the error in app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> The Promise returned from fetch() **won’t reject on HTTP error status**
>   even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve
>   normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on
>   network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

So you should check response.ok:

```
fetch(request, { method: 'GET' }).then(response => {
  return response.ok
    ? response.json()
    : Promise.reject(new Error('Response not ok'));
});
```

Comment: Those lines handle the 404 now, but i dont know how to mix it with my previous code. sorry to bother you that much!

Comment: @Fran Not sure what you mean by not being able to intergrate it. It is best to reject with an error type, the browser would reject with an error type if user is disconnected or if the site can't be reached for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like you have any try statements in there to fire the catch.

you got to have something like

```
try{
code to test
}
catch...
```

Comment: It's a promise there is a fetch().then().then().then()..catch()

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you, like say @fab put try ... catch inside the whole request function:

```
request(texto) {
  try{ // Added
    var request = "https://reqres.in/api/users/"+texto;
    fetch(request, {method: "GET"})
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // Actualizar el state con la respuesta
        //console.log(this.error);
        this.setState({nombre:responseJson.data.first_name})
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Actualizar el state indicando que los datos son erróneos
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({nombre:error})
      }).done();
  }

  requestCrear(nombre) {
    var request = "https://reqres.in/api/users";
    t(request, {method: "POST", headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }, body: JSON.stringify({name: nombre})})
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // Actualizar el state con la respuesta
        this.setState({nombre:responseJson.name})
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Actualizar el state indicando que los datos son erróneos
        this.setState({nombre:error})
      }).done();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ padding: 60}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Escribe un número para consultar"
          onSubmitEditing={
            (event) => {
              this.request(event.nativeEvent.text)
            }
          }
        />

        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Escribe un nombre para añadir una persona"
          onSubmitEditing={
            (event) => {
              this.requestCrear(event.nativeEvent.text)
            }
          }
        />
        <Text style={{padding: 20, fontSize: 42}}>
          {this.state.nombre}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }catch (e) { // Added
    console.log(e);
    // Here evaluate the error (e) ;
  }
}
```